# How to fetch column and its value from db using soapui free version (connection is established already)

Tags: jdbc, soapui

I want to see if any db entry came on that day by running it from soap ui
E.g. any 'Success' record came in X table
I have established the connection from soap to db but while passing the query i am getting error. Please suggest

Comment: Update your question with your code and the error you got so that we can help you.

Comment: What is the error? What is youd DBMS? What is your query? Please, provide this information to help someone to help you. You can check this article: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)